# Issue when Exporting Mesh to UnrealEd

Tags: mesh, export

Hello friends this is my first post here.. I just started my own project after tons of procrastinating, and after maybe 2 horus of Blender tutorials, i made a model. It's a submarine, i know it looks like a bomb but it's just the basic version, and it looks somewhat fine on Blender (and it's not finished yet).

[image: How it looks on Blender]

Now This is how the imported mesh looks on Unreal.
[image: How i t looks on UnrealEd]

How it looks on UnrealEd Now the problem comes when importing it to UnrealEd, it seems like it smooths out the edges of the Mesh. There msut be a problem when exporting right?

It looks ok if i uncheck the Apply Modifiers box, but it only renders half the submarine (Considering Mirror is a Blender modifier) and if i leave it checked it'll end up looking like pic 2. Even when selecting faces (which was the recommended option in the tutorial)

tl;dr Mesh looks ugly on unreal what should i do?

Answer (score -1):

Oh my. After a some search i've come up with the answers.

Followed [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22518253/how-to-handle-blenders-mirror-modifier-in-libgdx) and [This](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/24224/i-import-a-model-from-blender-to-unitybut-it-is-al.html) which are basically the same answer. Worked like a charm.

Comment: Please don't just add a link as an answer. Make a brief description of the contents of the links. If the links disappear or change your answer will not be helpful for others trying to solve similar issues.